# Taming non-human racial monsters in GruntHack

Tags: grunthack

[GruntHack](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/GruntHack) is one of the forks of NetHack, containing new features such as racial monsters, in which certain monsters can have different races (unlike in 
vanilla NetHack, in which they only ever had one race, often human). Now, I know that in both vanilla NetHack and in GruntHack, human monsters cannot be tamed. However, in GruntHack, can an individual monster with a nonhuman race (elf, dwarf, etc.) be tamed normally even if different members of its kind could be human (an example would be a player monster, which the GruntHack source code shows can appear randomly in the dungeon and can have different races)? I don't have GruntHack right now, which is why I can't test it myself.